# Comparing and substitution of opposite

Tags: python, list

I have a list with two items and I want `c` to equal the opposite of `b`?

```
a = ['rzz2', 'rzz3']
b = 'rzz2'
```

How can I get `c` to hold `'rzz3'`?

Comment: there's no such concept as opposite in the context you're providing

Comment: you want a complement, but is not the same at all

Comment: If your objective is just to remove the appearance of b in list a you can use a.remove(b). This removes only the first appearance of b in a.

Comment: what exactly is the opposite of `'rzz2'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the list only has two items, a simple [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) will work fine:

```
>>> a = ['rzz2', 'rzz3']
>>> b = 'rzz2'
>>> c = a[0] if a[0] != b else a[1]
>>> c
'rzz3'
>>>
```

Performance-wise, this is the fastest solution:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> a = ['rzz2', 'rzz3']
>>> b = 'rzz2'
>>> timeit('a[0] if a[0] != b else a[1]', 'from __main__ import a, b')
0.45458095931186787
>>> timeit('a[1 - a.index(b)]', 'from __main__ import a, b')
1.0331033692829674
>>> timeit('{b}.symmetric_difference(a)', 'from __main__ import a, b')
0.9464230789108647
>>> timeit('[i for i in a if i!=b][0]', 'from __main__ import a, b')
2.0873136110874384
>>>
```

Comment: +1 for the timeits... just out of curiosity, would you mind throwing in `dict(zip(a, reversed(a)))[b]`? Just curious as to how that compares

Comment: Never mind... it's slooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow... just a crazy idea...

Comment: @JonClements - (Sorry for the delay -- I was out).  Interestingly, a huge factor in that is the call to `reversed`.  Replacing that with `[::-1]` increased the performance substantially, going from `6.102846311472548` to `3.988217217551391` on my system.

Comment: It was a crazy idea anyway... just something that occurred to me... very good point about using `[::-1]` though - but even with that, it's still a dead snail. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be tempted to go for a set here, which may return zero or more results...

```
a = ['rzz2', 'rzz3']
b = 'rzz2'
print {b}.symmetric_difference(a)
# set(['rzz3'])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
c = a[1 - a.index(b)]
```

if its always a list of two ...

Comment: what if b is not in a?

Comment: then the opposite of None is Error , I quess.?

Comment: I am still figuring out the opposite of `'rzz2'`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [201]: a = ['rzz2', 'rzz3']

In [202]: b = 'rzz2'

In [203]: c = [i for i in a if i!=b][0]

In [204]: c
Out[204]: 'rzz3'

In [205]: c = a[1]

In [206]: c
Out[206]: 'rzz3'
```